# How do I set an SVG element to my page's favicon?

Tags: svg, favicon

I have an SVG element on my page. I want to use it as the page's favicon. How do I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doing this is *astoundingly* convoluted. You can see my solution in action [here](https://stuartpb.github.io/mindsightapps.com/logo-color.html): the methodology is described below (getting the HTML elements, by ID or otherwise, is left as an exercise for the reader).

### In the HTML

1. Make sure your SVG element includes the attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, as you're going to need to take the source of the element as its own file, and the XMLNS declaration is required for standalone SVG files. (Also note that this means your SVG will need to be self-contained and can't refer to elements in its parent document with something like `<use>`.)
2. Optionally, wrap the element in a `<div>` or `<span>`, which you may use to get the content of the `<svg>` element using `.innerHTML`. (Neither the `innerHTML` nor the `outerHTML` attributes are present on SVG elements in the current HTML standard.)
3. Include a `<link rel="icon">` in your page's `<head>`.

### In JavaScript

1. Get the source of the SVG element you want to set as your favicon by getting the `innerHTML` attribute of the HTML element you've wrapped it in, or by calling `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString()` on the SVG element.
2. Create a DataURL for this element as a document by prepending the string `"data:image/svg+xml,"` to the source. (If most browsers supported SVGs for favicons, we'd be done here, but since, at time of writing, they don't, *we must go deeper*.)
3. Create an `<img>` element that you'll be routing the image through, add an event listener to it for the `load` event that will draw the image once control returns to the event loop (as spec-compliant browsers won't let you read the image synchronously - [see this crbug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=755366)), and set the DataURL of your SVG source as its `src` attribute. (The steps between this and step 8 can happen either in sync now, or as part of the listener callback; they just need to happen before you draw the image.)
4. Decide what resolution you want to render your favicon to - My examples will use 64x64, for compatibility with high-DPI (Retina and Super Retina) displays.
5. Create a `<canvas>` element (heretofore referred to as `canvasElement`) and set its dimensions (by setting `canvasElement.width = 64` and `canvasElement.height = 64`).
6. Create a drawing context for the canvas using `canvasElement.getContext('2d')` (heretofore referred to as `ctx`).
7. If you're re-using a canvas you've created beforehand, set `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"`, or clear it with `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 64, 64)`.
8. Somewhere in the execution sequence following from the `load` listener you added to the `<img>` element you created in step 3, draw the image onto the canvas using `ctx.drawImage(svgImg, 0, 0, 64, 64)` (where `svgImg` is the `<img>` element you set the `src` to the SVG DataURL).
9. Create a PNG DataURL from the canvas using `canvasElement.toDataURL()`, and set *that* to the `href` attribute of the `<link rel="icon">` element in your HTML.

Comment: Also, you currently need to make sure there are `width` and `height` attributes specified on your `<svg>` element, due to https://crbug.com/475009.

Comment: It may also be faster to make a Blob for the canvas using [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), saving the Base64-encoding step.

Comment: Which browsers does this support?

Comment: This *should* work in all current browsers (supporting Canvas, drawImage, and toBlob and/or toDataURL), and at time of writing, it did; however, this appears to be currently broken in Chrome due to [a pretty nasty regression bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=755366).

Comment: @ElliotLabs I've updated the post to fix the part that relied on out-of-spec behavior (which triggered the bug I linked in above when Chrome fixed their spec compliance): the procedure described here should work in all modern browsers.

Comment: For older browsers that weren't as consistent in their image loading behavior, you should follow the behavior I describe in step 3 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/34440779/34799 to sniff out whether they make the image accessible synchronously or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and this worked for me:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.svg" type="image/svg">
```

Change the `type="image/x-icon"` to `type="image/svg"`.

Answer (score 0):

I know its already answered but It too much work for such a simple task just store your svg in a svg file and use it as favicon in Head Tag.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Even in 2021 support isn't uniform across the different browsers - https://caniuse.com/link-icon-svg

Comment: Yes, its major problem in mobile browsers , this causes ugly UI

Comment: type="image/x-icon" is NOT CORRECT for svg images. One should either remove the incorrect type or replace it with ```type="image/svg"```