# Unable to convert svg, with viewbox attribute, to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

Hi guys I am trying to convert svg to canvas and download it.Here is my code :-

```
    var h=$("#"+chartId).find('svg').height();
    var w=$("#"+chartId).find('svg').width();
    var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas1.id     = "canvas1";
    canvas1.width  = w;
    canvas1.height = h;
    document.getElementById('pngcon').appendChild(canvas1);

    var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById(chartId).querySelector('svg'));

    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasdata;
    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;
    window.open(imgsrc);
    image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        var data = context.getImageData(0, 0,w , h);
        var compositeOperation = context.globalCompositeOperation;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
        context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        context.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
        data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1.0);
        canvasdata = data;

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.id="imagepng"
        a.download = chartname+".png";
        a.href = canvasdata;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        document.getElementById("imagepng").click();
        $("#pngcon").html('');

        $("#imagepng").remove();

    };
```

Everything works fine when svg doesn't have viewbox attribute set, like this

```
<svg  id="svg_chart2">
......
......
</svg>
```

But when i add viewbox attribute in svg, the program stops working,like follows:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 651 348 " id="svg_chart2">
......
......
</svg>
```

Please help...

Comment: I’d try overwriting the viewbox attribute before serializing the SVG then … (whether that will get you the expected _result_ however is not certain.)

Comment: Hi @CBroe i've already tried your solution, seem not to be working! I am actually new to Javascript, so can you please explain your solution(with code, may be I am implementing it incorrectly).

Comment: In my experience, SVG images don't render without the `xmlns` attribute. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232982/how-do-i-set-an-svg-element-to-my-pages-favicon).

Comment: Also, you don't have to call `btoa` on the SVG source. Just remove `;base64` from the URL prefix, and you can specify the rest of the URL in plain text.