# Is there a way to render SVG favicons in unsupported browsers?

Tags: svg, favicon

As of right now, the only browser that seems to support them is Firefox. Apparently Opera used to support it but later dropped it. Perhaps a JavaScript shim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any shims. Unfortunately, I don't think there are any that would work, since a favicon is displayed in the browser user interface rather than on the website itself. However, I do believe the browser support situation is finally starting to improve. As of now, an SVG icon in Firefox only loads on the first page load, and then falls back to `.png` or `.ico` favicons if any. [The upcoming Safari 9 also has partial support](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html), with using single-colored SVG favicons for the new "pinned tabs" feature - but that requires the SVG to be completely black, have an unofficial `mask` attribute included, and if you want, define a single color the whole icon should be colored using the (unrelated) `<meta name="theme-color">` tag. [Firefox seems to be working on a fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=366324) *(update: fixed in Firefox 41)*, and all the other browsers have a feature request site for SVG favicons to be implemented ([Edge](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6509196-svg-favicons), [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294179) and [Webkit/Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136059)).

For now, along with specifying `<link rel="icon" sizes="any" href="favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">`, you should continue specifying a `.png` and/or `.ico` icon as well.

Comment: I found something - maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232982/how-do-i-set-an-svg-element-to-my-pages-favicon#answer-20232983) could help? It converts the SVG to a `<canvas>`, and then to a PNG.

Comment: It's probably best to just keep using both a SVG and a PNG for now. I hope more browsers start supporting SVG favicons, seeing as how many various sizes different browsers use.

Is there a way to force Firefox to use the SVG instead of the PNG? The SVG file is much smaller and I would prefer that supporting browsers such as Firefox would use it rather than the PNG.

Comment: @Brandon I totally agree - make sure to vote on the [Edge UserVoice site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/6509196-svg-favicons), for instance. Firefox seems to use the last favicon specified (some use the first in the list, too - it's a real mess), so I have my `<link rel=icon href=favicon.svg>` as my last `<link rel=icon>`, and that's the one showing up in Firefox 41+ (I don't know what's being loaded in the background, though). Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

Reusing the non-serialization-related parts of the procedure from [How do I set an SVG element to my page's favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232982/how-do-i-set-an-svg-element-to-my-pages-favicon):

1. Create a `<canvas>` element (hereafter referred to as `canvasElement`).
2. Create an `<img>` element (hereafter referred to as `imageElement`) and set its `href` to your SVG icon.
3. Once the image is loaded (by checking the `complete` property of the element after setting the `href`, calling the following steps directly if so and adding them as a listener for the `load` event if not), set the canvas dimensions to match with `canvasElement.width = imageElement.width` and `canvasElement.height = imageElement.height`).
4. Create a drawing context for the canvas using `canvasElement.getContext('2d')` (hereafter referred to as `ctx`).
5. Draw the image (after setting `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"`, especially if re-using the canvas element) onto the canvas using `ctx.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height)`.
6. Create a PNG DataURL from the canvas using `canvasElement.toDataURL()`, and set *that* to the `href` attribute of the `<link rel="icon">` element in your HTML.

Comment: Note that all modern browsers, following the behavior described in the HTML Living Standard for image loading, shouldn't set the `complete` property until after the `load` event fires: see [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20232983/34799) for a rewritten version expecting spec-compliant behavior.